# Android DialogFragment doesn't WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I have a `DialogFragment` being being shown when an `TextView` is clicked. This `DialogFragment` has it's own XML layout file with a `ListView`, and a `EditText` and `Button` at the bottom.

The problem is that when the `ListView` has only a few items, the `DialogFragment` still takes up most of the screen (i.e. the height is much larger than it should be.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean (the black is the `ListView` with one item):

[image]

As you can see there is an abundance of blank space above the `ListView` when I want the `Dialog` to be only the size it needs to be.

Here is the `DialogFragent` XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
    tools:context="com.cohenadair.anglerslog.fragments.ManageFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_item_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/new_item_edit"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/hint_new_item"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_add"
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/add_item_layout"
        android:id="@+id/content_list_view"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_primitive, container, false);

    int primitiveId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PRIMITIVE_ID);
    PrimitiveFragmentInfo info = FragmentUtils.primitiveInfo(getActivity(), primitiveId);

    if (info != null) {
        initViews(view, info);
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it by switching from `RelativeLayout` and using `LinearLayout` with the `layout_weight` property.

Here's the new XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.cohenadair.anglerslog.fragments.ManageFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/content_list_view">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_item_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/new_item_edit"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/hint_new_item"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_add"
            android:id="@+id/add_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But, problem with RelativeLayout remains.

Comment: @DevetiPutnik correct.  I was never able to figure out why `RelativeLayout` didn't work, or a proper solution using `RelativeLayout`.  This answer is obviously just a workaround.